# Unable to Access Windows Partition

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, mount, windows, ntfs

I wanted to copy some files from ubuntu to my windows partition which was read only, I used the command sudo cp -aR 1/* /dev/sda3 and now I am unable to boot into windows. I get unknown error when trying to mount the drive. Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did overwrite your Windows partition with the contents of the files you copied. Maybe you can recover something using data recovery software, but it may be as well that the data is lost.

Using names like `/dev/sda3` means **raw device access** - you are writing the data straight away to the partition, overwriting whatever is there.

If you wanted to copy files to your Windows partition, you should mount the partition first and then copy files to the directory where you mounted the partition.

If the partition was read only, that was probably due to unclean Windows shutdown before you booted into Linux. Windows sets a "dirty" flag on the partition in that case, causing Linux to mount it read-only. You should have fixed the partition problem first (probably in Windows), and then mount it again properly in Linux.

Comment: but i am unable to mount it now any way to solve this?

Comment: You can't mount it because it is destroyed. You destroyed it yourself. Your only hope is now data recovery software or a professional data recovery service.

Comment: Or if you don't care about the data on that partition, reformat it and reinstall Windows.

Comment: any way to recover it from ubuntu

Comment: I don't know what data recovery software is available for Ubuntu. Maybe someone else will answer.

Comment: And also I can see windows option in the grub still

Comment: Because you didn't overwrite GRUB; you did only overwrite the Windows partition. But that option will not work and Windows will not boot.

Comment: Thanks for the info